# Make multiple monitors go to sleep with Windows API?

Tags: winapi, sleep, power-management, multiple-monitors

How exactly would I make both of my monitors go to sleep, I want to write an application myself because I'd like to add certain functionality, and so far I can't find anything on MSDN relating to making your display go to sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like:

```
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2);
```

It should work on dual monitors.

Although it [might be best not to use HWND_BROADCAST, but instead to use a HWND from your app's own window](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/06/13/629451.aspx). You don't say what language you're using, but if it's C# or VB.NET, there are plenty of samples about demonstrating how to call this from those languages.

Comment: I'm using C++ and it's a console application, I call FreeConsole(); to hide the console as soon at it is executed. The call worked exactly like I wanted it to, but since I have no visible window, do I need to use my own HWND?

Comment: At first I thought `GetShellWindow()` was the correct answer but now I'm not so sure...

Comment: The link provided redirects to an inaccessible resource.

Comment: @Akito it was posted 13 years ago

Comment: @stuartd And? StackOverflow does not care about it, since all question updates are labelled as "duplicates". This means, a 13 year old answer has to be valid today, as well.

Comment: Maybe I got the URL wrong and nobody noticed before - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060612-00/?p=30903

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `SC_MONITORPOWER` option to the [WM_SYSCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360(VS.85).aspx) message.

There is a CodeProject [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Monitor_management_guide.aspx) for C#.